# What encoding is this for Gif image?

Tags: encoding, gif, decoding

I wanted to download an image from the web. But when I 'save image', it opens as a .txt file. I figure this is some type of encoding for the image but I can't find out which.

I want to eventually automate downloading the image for further processing, specifically text recognition. I've tried to convert the .txt using some online base64 encoders/decoders with no success. However, https://convertio.co/  was able to convert the .txt to .gif but I don't know how it did what it did.

I've given a sample of the .txt file. The actual file is much bigger.

The file name beings as such (if it helps): 
data:image;base64,R0lGODlhyABGAIMAAPRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNvRDNv///ywAAAAAyABGAAAE+vDB (and it goes on, its very long).

```
GIF89aÈ�F�ƒ��ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ôC6ÿÿÿ,����È�F��úðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|úðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|úðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|úðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ|ðÁ;
```

I can see that there are '|' characters in between. May be for separating pixels.

The entire file is here: https://pastebin.com/BPbTHMZ7

Comment: Probably that *is* the GIF. You just need to change the file extension to ".gif".

Comment: Can you use a tool (for example https://pastebin.com/) to provide the full txt?

Comment: @deceze I've already tried that, it didnt work.

Comment: @Pims here it is: https://pastebin.com/BPbTHMZ7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems to be a GIF image encoded as a data URL:

```
data:image;base64,R0lGODlhyABGAIMAAPRDNvRDNvRDNvR...
```

This format can be used in HTML and CSS file and is handy because the image data is directly embedded in the HTML/CSS file and does not need to be loaded with a separate request.

The start of the text basically says it's *data* URL, containing data for an *image* and the image is encoded using *Base 64*.

To decode it:

1. Chop off the start of the text, namely `data:image;base64,`.
2. Run the remaining text (`R0lGODlhy...`) through a Base64 decoder. The result will be binary data.
3. Save the binary data to a file using a file name with the extension `.gif`.

Now you have a proper GIF image as a file.